# iOS : Present a notification when the background treatment is finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, notifications, uilocalnotification

I want to display to the user a notification which is displayed when the application ends the background treatment.

This is the code which I currently use :

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Your uploads are finished";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
```

But it does not works, when I called endBackgroundTask, I don't see the notification.
However, I used breakpoints, and this code is executed.

Comment: Is your background task asynchronous, like a network task for example ? If so, the task could have not finished when the app goes to background ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   //identify the application state you through the Local notification
   UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];

 if (state==UIApplicationStateInactive)
  {
                    //Show the notification as text voice
                    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
                    [notification setAlertBody:"title"];
                    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                    notification.alertAction = @"View";
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
                }
```

Comment: By identify the application state of your app  we can through the Local notification.